# How do you parse comparison structures?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How do you parse structures that make a comparison – specifically *as* ... *as* and *more/-er* ... *than*?

Example 1:

*He is as cute as an angel* – here I would analyse *as cute as an angel* as an AdjP functioning as a subject predicative complement, where *cute* is the head of the AdjP, but how do I analyse the rest of the AdjP?

Example 2:
*He is much older than I am* – here I would analyse *much older than I am* as an AdjP functioning as a subject predicative complement, where *older* is the head of the AdjP, *much* is a premodifier, and *than I am* is an adjective complement. Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there no-one who can help me out here?

Comment: Hannah, is it possible you're over-complicating something which is actually more simple?

Comment: Robbie, sorry I didn't see this before! It may very well be that I'm over-complicating (not the first time in that case...) – so, what would the simple answer be then, would you say? :)

Comment: Sorry, Hannah. I really don't understand how you could make that so complicated *unless it belonged between you and you teacher…*

Comment: Um... ok... I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but how would you parse the above examples in a less complicated way then? And I haven't really got a teacher... I just want to know how to parse comparison structures :)

Comment: Then sorry again and I give up. By *unless it belonged between you and your teacher* I was trynig not to say I thought it didn't belong here.

Comment: Hm. Looking at other posts in the forum, I fail to see how this doesn't belong here? And you still haven't told me the very simple answer that is apparently out there – why do you keep telling me I'm overcomplicating, only to then give up, without having even tried to tell me what your SIMPLE solution is? Why not just ANSWER my question, instead of saying it's stupid? Why are you patronising me instead of explaining?

Comment: Sorry, Hannah. How many people have leapt in to help you with this and how strongly might that indicate belonging? I told you "I give up"
I stressed "by unless it belonged between you and your teacher I was trying not to say I thought it didn't belong here…"

What made me give up was the complexity you brought to the Question. Why is that not allowed, please?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to be rude – I read your "I give up" as rolling your eyes at me, basically. If I misunderstood you, I apologise. Really. I'm STILL curious about the LESS complex analysis though ;) Or are you saying that parsing of comparison structures IS very complex, and that THAT's why it doesn't belong here?

Comment: No, Hannah. Exactly the opposite. Please think deeply about that…